# How to merge rows in a Dataframe based on a previous row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sequentially ordered dataframe that represent two events measured over time - the measurements are the start and end times of the event. They *should* be ordered in an ABABAB sequence, but in some cases I may have consecutive events of the same type (i.e. ABABAABABB). I am looking for a way to check the event label (A or B) in each row with the previous event label, and if they are the same to merge the rows in such a way that I maintain the start time of the first event and the end time of the second event. Consider the following:

```
myDF = pd.DataFrame({"Event": ["A","B","A","A","B","B","A"], 
                 "Start": [1,3,5,7,9,11,13], 
                 "End": [2,4,6,8,10,12,14]})
```

**What I currently have...**

```
==============================
  Event      Start      End
==============================
    A          1         2
    B          3         4
    A          5         6
    A          7         8
    B          9         10
    B          11        12
    A          13        14
==============================
```

**What I need...**

**Note:** The two A events at index position 2-3 have been merged into one, as have the two B events originally at positions 4-5.

```
==============================
  Event      Start      End
==============================
    A          1         2
    B          3         4
    A          5         8
    B          9         12
    A          13        14
==============================
```

I had initially thought to use `groupby` but I don't think this right as this will group over the entire dataframe. Similarly I have tried using `iteritems` but have not had any success. Apologies for the lack of code but I'm at a loss as to how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`GroupBy.agg`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `first` and `last`.

```py
g = df["Event"].ne(df["Event"].shift()).cumsum()
df.groupby(g, as_index = False).agg({
  "Event": "first",
  "Start": "first",
  "End": "last"
})

  Event  Start  End
0     A      1    2
1     B      3    4
2     A      5    8
3     B      9   12
4     A     13   14
```

Comment: @HenryYik Yes you're right. Edited the answer. Thank you

Comment: @Ch3steR thanks, that's just what i need. For my own understanding, are 'first' and 'last' understood as keywords in GroupBy.agg? I'm used to seeing anything as a string as being user specified.

Comment: Not keyword they they just short-hand for `GroupByfirst()` and `GroupBy.last()`, pandas maintains a dictionary for mapping these e.g `{'mean':np.mean, 'median':np.median, ...}` now `.groupby(...).agg('mean')` would call `np.mean`

Comment: For more info you search in their github repo `pandas/core/base.py` in which they have `_cython_table` which maintains these short-hands @DC_Liv

Answer (score 1):

Another way can be

```
for i in range(1,myDF.shape[0]):
    if myDF['Event'][i] == myDF['Event'][i-1]:
        myDF.loc[i, ('Start')]= min(myDF['Start'][i],myDF['Start'][i-1])
        myDF.loc[i, ('End')]= max(myDF['End'][i],myDF['End'][i-1])
        myDF.drop([i-1],inplace=True)
```